# How to get key Value from cookies which was set in javascript, asp.net mvc3

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, cookies

I had set a cookie in javascript some thing like this

```
   function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
    {
       var exdate=new Date();
       exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
       var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
       document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
    }

var  loginval = slmgusername=swetha.p + slmguserpassword = 12345678;
 setCookie("slmgusercredentails", loginval, 100);
```

And i controller i am getting values in my cookie  like this

```
 HttpContext.Request.Cookies["slmgusercredentials"].Values = {slmgusername%253Dswetha.p%2526slmguserpassword%253D12345678}
```

when i am trying to get the username from this some thing like

```
 UserName = HttpContext.Request.Cookies["slmgusercredentials"].Values["slmgusername"].
```

I cant able to get the UserName. As i think so the values are in javscript coding format. How to get the username... can any one help me to find the solution...

Comment: Please tag this question with your back-end framework (ASP?).  It helps to mention it explicitly in the question text, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do the trick!

```
 function ReadCookie()
    {
       var allcookies = document.cookie;
       alert("All Cookies : " + allcookies );

       // Get all the cookies pairs in an array
       cookiearray  = allcookies.split(';');

       // Now take key value pair out of this array
       for(var i=0; i<cookiearray.length; i++){
          name = cookiearray[i].split('=')[0];
          value = cookiearray[i].split('=')[1];
          alert("Key is : " + name + " and Value is : " + value);
       }
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't work for `key=value;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT`. `expires` considered as another cookie

Comment: @dr.dimitru Of course it works, he splits key-values pairs on line 7

Answer (score 1):

Solves the expired problem from accepted answer.

```
function readKeyValuesFromCookie(){
    return document.cookie
        .split( ';' )
        .map( pair => pair.split( '=' ) )
        .filter( pair => pair.length == 2 )
        .map( pair => [ pair[0].trim(), pair[1].trim() ] )
        .filter( pair => pair[0] != 'expires' )
    ;
}
```